# C# Generics method - calling base class constructor on a type

Tags: c#, generics, visual-studio-2012

I have an Object called CAR declared as follows:

```
public class Car{
   public int NumberOfWheels;
}
```

and using another class I can retrieve three of its subclasses.
As follows:

```
public TruckA getCarA(int param){
   return new TruckA () {NumberOfWheels = param} 
}
public TruckB getCarB(int param){
   return new TruckB () {NumberOfWheels = param} 
}
public TruckC getCarC(int param){
   return new TruckC () {NumberOfWheels = param} 
}
```

How do I write in using generics ?
(I know it is too simple, I need an example for a more complicated case)

I want to create a method that creates a new (T), enters the parameter and returns it.

something like

```
public TruckC getCarC(int param){
   return getTruck<TruckC>(param)
}
```

Only that :
1. TruckA/B/C dont have constructor.
2. Car has no constructor. initialized using {}.
3. The method should receive only classes that derive from Car so that it can use its initialization ( {} ).

(something equivalent to  ?? extends ? in java generics)
Possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Google for generic type constraints.

Comment: `1. TruckA/B/C dont have constructor.
2. Car has one constructor (i assume not parameterless).` It is impossible.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan author omitted TruckX definitions so you don't know if it has parameterless constructor or not. But obviously it has, because he calls it

Comment: @deej Look at closer. From OP `1. TruckA/B/C dont have constructor.`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan You made me doubt. But if 2 then 1 is impossible. So i suppose 1 means that TruckX has explicit parameterless constructor

Comment: `But if 2 then 1 is impossible.` Of course. As mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan thanks. I tried to simplify the problem and missed that. I have updated my question with your note. initialization is done using {}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```cs
private static T GetTruck<T>(int param) where T : Car, new()
{
    return new T() {NumberOfWheels = param} ;
}
```

Comment: @rails Have you tried this with 1. TruckA/B/C dont have constructor.
2. Car has one constructor(public Car(int param)) ?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan : The solution works. But thanks for noticing my mistake. In my real code I use {} to initialize and the members are private. I have updated this mistake in my question.

Answer (score 1):

**try this :**

```
public T getCarC<T>(int param) where T : Car, new()
        {
            T truck=new T();
            truck.NumberOfWheels = param;

            return track;
        }
```

Generics are the most powerful feature of C# 2.0. Generics allow you to define type-safe data structures, without committing to actual data types.

**When deriving from a generic base class, you must provide a type argument instead of the base-class's generic type parameter:**

```
public class BaseClass<T>
{...}
public class SubClass : BaseClass<int>
{...}
```

**If the subclass is generic, instead of a concrete type argument, you can use the subclass generic type parameter as the specified type for the generic base class:**

```
public class SubClass<T> : BaseClass<T> 
{...}
```

**When using the subclass generic type parameters, you must repeat any constraints stipulated at the base class level at the subclass level. For example, derivation constraint:**

```
public class BaseClass<T>  where T : ISomeInterface 
{...}
public class SubClass<T> : BaseClass<T> where T : ISomeInterface
{...}
```

**Or constructor constraint:**

```
public class BaseClass<T>  where T : new()
{   
   public T SomeMethod()
   {
      return new T();
   }
}
public class SubClass<T> : BaseClass<T> where T : new() 
{...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this using generic type constraints. These let you make requirements about the type that is passed.

It would look something like this:

```
public static T GetCar<T>(int param)
    where T : Car, new() // Must inherit from Car, must have a parameterless constructor
{
    return new T() { NumberOfWheels = param };
}
```